# Custom Sorting: If Parent Node contains child nodes I need to check each child node attribute names and then extract text from that element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I mentioned below my sample xml file.
  I want to display `value` tag text in My own order format.
    EX: first I want to display   `Value AttributeID="13222"` then 
    `Value AttributeID="113458"` like this, I need to arrange the position according to AttributeId.

**Sample.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
    <Values>     
      <Value AttributeID="113458" AttributeName="0180 - Text - remainder">
        <Text>
          <style name="TextHead1">The current enterprise application landscape</style>
          <style name="TextStyle1">
            <character name="linebreak" />Introduction of the Title
            <style name="bold">
              The smallest font size
              <character name="linebreak" />
              for which kerning should be automatically adjusted.
              <character name="linebreak" />
              and some manual work done.
            </style>
            <style name="bold">
              Reference for this book<style name="superscript">1</style>
            </style>     
        </Text>
      </Value>
      <Value AttributeID="13335" AttributeName="0190 - Text - remainder">
        <Text>
          <style name="TextHead1">The Bussiness application landscape</style>
          <style name="TextStyle1">
            Introduction of the Title
            <style name="bold">
              The smallest font size for which kerning should be automatically adjusted and some manual work done.
            </style>
             <style name="SimpleTag target=&quot;http://www.example.com/financing /uk&quot;"><style name="URL_bold">ibm.com</style></style>
            <style name="italic">
              Reference for this book<style name="superscript">1</style>
            </style>
            <style name="bulletStyle1">none: No leader line</style>
            <style name="bulletStyle1">dot: Dotted leader line</style>
          </Text>
      </Value>   
    <Value AttributeID="13222" AttributeName="0200 - Text - remainder">
        <Text>
          <style name="TextHead1">the world’s largest florist and gift shop</style>
          <style name="TextStyle1">
            Introduction of the Title, It is also introducing environmental responsibility as a theme across all of its businesses,        
              The smallest font size for some manual work done.       
             <style name="SimpleTag target=&quot;http://www.example.com/financing /uk&quot;"><style name="URL_bold">ibm.com</style></style>
            <style name="italic">
              Reference for this book<style name="superscript">1</style>
            </style>
            <style name="bulletStyle1">environmental responsibility</style>
            <style name="bulletStyle1">world’s largest florist</style>
          </Text>
      </Value>     
    </Values>
```

Comment: So what is your question? Do you want the `Value` elements sorted in numerical order by their AttributeID? You say you want `13222`, then `113458`, but in that case, where does `13335` go?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your example how to set customozed sorting in XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:template match="Values">
        <values>
          <xsl:for-each select="Value">
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="ascending"
              select="(number(@AttributeID='13222') * 1)
          + (number(@AttributeID='113458') * 2)
          + (number(@AttributeID='13335') * 3) "/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </values>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**INPUT XML** as your XML was not well-formed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<Values>     
  <Value AttributeID="113458" AttributeName="0180 - Text - remainder">
    <Text>
      <style name="TextHead1">The current enterprise application landscape</style>
      <style name="TextStyle1">
            <character name="linebreak" />Introduction of the Title
            <style name="bold">
              The smallest font size
              <character name="linebreak" />
              for which kerning should be automatically adjusted.
              <character name="linebreak" />
              and some manual work done.
            </style>
            <style name="bold">
              Reference for this book<style name="superscript">1</style>
            </style>
        </style>
        </Text>
  </Value>
  <Value AttributeID="13335" AttributeName="0190 - Text - remainder">
    <Text>
      <style name="TextHead1">The Bussiness application landscape</style>
      <style name="TextStyle1">
            Introduction of the Title
            <style name="bold">
              The smallest font size for which kerning should be automatically adjusted and some manual work done.
            </style>
             <style name="SimpleTag target=&quot;http://www.example.com/financing /uk&quot;"><style name="URL_bold">ibm.com</style></style>
            <style name="italic">
              Reference for this book<style name="superscript">1</style>
            </style>
            <style name="bulletStyle1">none: No leader line</style>
            <style name="bulletStyle1">dot: Dotted leader line</style>
        </style>
          </Text>
  </Value>   
  <Value AttributeID="13222" AttributeName="0200 - Text - remainder">
    <Text>
      <style name="TextHead1">the world’s largest florist and gift shop</style>
      <style name="TextStyle1">
            Introduction of the Title, It is also introducing environmental responsibility as a theme across all of its businesses,        
              The smallest font size for some manual work done.       
             <style name="SimpleTag target=&quot;http://www.example.com/financing /uk&quot;"><style name="URL_bold">ibm.com</style></style>
            <style name="italic">
              Reference for this book<style name="superscript">1</style>
            </style>
            <style name="bulletStyle1">environmental responsibility</style>
            <style name="bulletStyle1">world’s largest florist</style>
        </style>
          </Text>
  </Value>     
</Values>
```

**generated output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><values><Value AttributeID="13222" AttributeName="0200 - Text - remainder">
    <Text>
      <style name="TextHead1">the world’s largest florist and gift shop</style>
      <style name="TextStyle1">
            Introduction of the Title, It is also introducing environmental responsibility as a theme across all of its businesses,        
              The smallest font size for some manual work done.       
             <style name="SimpleTag target=&#34;http://www.example.com/financing /uk&#34;"><style name="URL_bold">ibm.com</style></style>
            <style name="italic">
              Reference for this book<style name="superscript">1</style>
            </style>
            <style name="bulletStyle1">environmental responsibility</style>
            <style name="bulletStyle1">world’s largest florist</style>
        </style>
          </Text>
  </Value><Value AttributeID="113458" AttributeName="0180 - Text - remainder">
    <Text>
      <style name="TextHead1">The current enterprise application landscape</style>
      <style name="TextStyle1">
            <character name="linebreak"/>Introduction of the Title
            <style name="bold">
              The smallest font size
              <character name="linebreak"/>
              for which kerning should be automatically adjusted.
              <character name="linebreak"/>
              and some manual work done.
            </style>
            <style name="bold">
              Reference for this book<style name="superscript">1</style>
            </style>
        </style>
        </Text>
  </Value><Value AttributeID="13335" AttributeName="0190 - Text - remainder">
    <Text>
      <style name="TextHead1">The Bussiness application landscape</style>
      <style name="TextStyle1">
            Introduction of the Title
            <style name="bold">
              The smallest font size for which kerning should be automatically adjusted and some manual work done.
            </style>
             <style name="SimpleTag target=&#34;http://www.example.com/financing /uk&#34;"><style name="URL_bold">ibm.com</style></style>
            <style name="italic">
              Reference for this book<style name="superscript">1</style>
            </style>
            <style name="bulletStyle1">none: No leader line</style>
            <style name="bulletStyle1">dot: Dotted leader line</style>
        </style>
          </Text>
  </Value></values>
```

Comment: Can you create XML to HTML using XSLT and add all Styles to the tags, What i mentioned in <Style> tag. Can you code using <xsl:for-each> and <xsl:if test=""> conditions.

Comment: Your question was on sorting only. If you need XML to HTML output, create another post with input and output snippet requirement.